# IE7 scrollbars when position:relative item WAS out-of-screen

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

IE7 seems to show scrollbars when an item that has position: relative on it USED to cause a scroll-bar (e.g. it would if you took `position: relative` off).

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="inner box"></div>
</div>

.box {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 5px;
    left     : 100px;
    right    : 5px;
    height   : 100px;
    border   : 1px solid #000;
}

.inner {
    right    : auto;
    position : relative;
    width    : 110%;
    left     : -90px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VE9ne/1/

Wondering if anyone has seen this and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like appropriate behavior. You could try negative margins. Use left:0;margin-left:-90px;

Comment: `margin-left` works: http://jsfiddle.net/VE9ne/4/

Comment: @Gerben - post that as an answer and I'll accept it.  I don't think, however, that it's appropriate behavior as the parent div is absolutely positioned, so the space left by the element shouldn't count towards anything (every other browser, IE8 included work properly with this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use negative margins instead of negative left

```
...
left:0;
margin-left:-90px;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what relative positioning does, it leaves an empty space at the object's original position if you offset it. I guess IE7 is not as smart as other browsers so it will show scrollbars whereas others seem to realize there's nothing but empty space to show.

Here's what w3.org has to say about it:

> [...] Offsetting a box (B1) in this
>   way has no effect on the box (B2) that
>   follows: B2 is given a position as if
>   B1 were not offset and B2 is not
>   re-positioned after B1's offset is
>   applied. [...]

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#relative-positioning

Using **margins and floats** instead of relative positioning could solve your problem

Comment: +1 for the reference, but there is no "following box" in this case, and the paren't isn't causing the issue either since it's absolutely positioned.  Therefore the "empty space" is being caused by a "shadow"

Comment: In Firefox 4 I do get a scroll bar by using a negative top value ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/CK5Zz/1/)), but not in IE9 . I think margins and floats are better practices than relative positioning!

Comment: I'll agree with margins, but I try to never use floats.  There are too many browser bugs associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
html, body
{
overflow: hidden;
}
```